# C++ to print to a file with cases and arrays

Tags: c++

Ok, so this program has been shortened to make it easier to read. There would obviously be more case statements to go along with the amount of variables there are. My question is why does my program get an error every time it runs. It is fine when it compiles but not when I run it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string thearray[22960];
    char bigfor[10];
    int arrayvar = 0;
    int finishedarray;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
    int h;
    int i;
    int j;

    // Constants

    int variable1 = 0;
    int variable2 = 1;
    int variable3 = 2;
    int variable4 = 3;
    int variable5 = 4;
    int variable6 = 5;
    int variable7 = 6;
    int variable8 = 7;
    int variable9 = 8;
    int variable10 = 9;




    for (a = 0; a < 36; a++)
    {
        switch (a)

        {
        case 0:
            bigfor[variable1] = '0';
            break;
        case 1:
            bigfor[variable1] = '1';
            break;
        case 2:
            bigfor[variable1] = '2';
            break;
        case 3:
            bigfor[variable1] = '3';
            break;
        case 4:
            bigfor[variable1] = '4';
            break;
        case 5:
            bigfor[variable1] = '5';
            break;
        case 6:
            bigfor[variable1] = '6';
            break;
        case 7:
            bigfor[variable1] = '7';
            break;
        case 8:
            bigfor[variable1] = '8';
            break;
        case 9:
            bigfor[variable1] = '9';
            break;
        }

        thearray[arrayvar] = bigfor[variable1] + bigfor[variable2] + bigfor[variable4] +
                             bigfor[variable5] + bigfor[variable6] + bigfor[variable7] + 
                             bigfor[variable8] + bigfor[variable9] + bigfor[variable10];


        arrayvar = arrayvar + 1;
    }

    finishedarray = arrayvar + 1;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("codes.txt");

    for (arrayvar = 0; a < finishedarray; a++)
    {
        myfile << thearray[arrayvar] << endl;
    }

    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your program failing to do? What errors are you getting? ...

Comment: Can u tell us more about the error..?

Comment: Might I suggest that instead of: `variable1=0, variable2=1 ... ` do: `enum { someUsefulName, someOtherUsefulName, anotherUsefulName }` ... it does the same exact thing, takes up 1/1000000000th the space and enhances readability (given that your usefulNames are actually useful).

Comment: Oh and that is a VERY large number of strings... since you're using C++ why not just use a `std::vector<std::string>` or a `std::list<std::string>`?

Comment: What is variable2 through variable10 used for?  Why do you need a switch statement?  Can't you use '0' + someIndex ?

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you are reading uninitialized values here:

```
thearray[arrayvar] = bigfor[variable1]+ bigfor[variable2] + bigfor[variable4] +
bigfor[variable5] + bigfor[variable6] + bigfor[variable7] + bigfor[variable8] + 
bigfor[variable9] + bigfor[variable10];
```

This is *undefined behaviour*. At this point in the program, only `bigfor[variable1]` is initialized.

Whatever you are trying to do, I have a feeling there is a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the addition you were doing. The addition will only add the integer-encoded values of the ASCII characters, and result in an integer. This will cause an error because you can't assign an integer to a `std::string`.

In addition to @juanchopanza's answer, your code can be improved substantially. For example, instead of listing out the indices manually, you can do this instead within your for loop:

```
std::string bigfor;

for (int a = 0; a < 36; ++a)
{
    bigfor += (a + 48);
}

std::ofstream myfile("codes.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < bigfor.size(); ++i)
{
    myfile << bigfor[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, '0' is better than 48.  Some may point out that something compatible with other character sets is even better.

Comment: with the code I have just added when it adds the letters and numbers to the file if it adds any more than one it deletes the previous one and doesn't go to the next line.

Comment: @majinvegeta010688 Use this code only and see what happens. This is my attempt at shortening your own program.